# Is $\sigma (Y_{1},...,Y_{n})$ generally not the equal to $\sigma (\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i})$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

As above: Is $\sigma (Y_{1},...,Y_{n})$ generally not the equal to $\sigma (\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i})$ where $Y_{i}$ is a random variable?

I do not believe that they are equal, but are there conditions that may be useful to draw some kind of equivalence between the two sets?

Comment: Knowing the sum of some random variables is generally much less information than knowing all of them.. for instance, if $Y_1 = X$ and $Y_2 = -X$ then by learning the sum you learn nothing. Did this question come from some desired application?

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what about the other way around, i.e. can any element of $\sigma( \sum Y_{i})$ be found in $\sigma(Y_{1},..,Y_{n})$?

Comment: Yes. This is because the sum function is measurable, and this implies that $\Sigma Y_i$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(Y_i)$.

Comment: Well, if $Y_i=0$ with probability one, then $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i=0$ with probability one, so the two $\sigma$-algebras would be equal. But that is not very useful, I imagine.